# What's wrong with this Postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
: SELECT created_at, count(created_at) as count FROM "candidates"  GROUP BY date(created_at)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "candidates.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

`created_at` is a datetime column

`candidates` is a table

How do I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: As a note, in Postgres `date` isn't a function.  It works with the parentheses, but would more typically be written without the parentheses `group by date created_at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting `created_at` also as a separate column. You need to use an aggregate function (like `MIN` or `MAX`) around it or add it to the `GROUP BY`.

Since you are already grouping by `date(created_at)` you probably want to use that in the select instead. So something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(created_at),
    COUNT(created_at) as count
FROM "candidates"
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```